# How do I split nested objects into its separate objects in es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, nested-lists

My json data currently looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 345345,
        "status": {
            "code": 200,
            "success": true,
            "message": "Success",
            "errors": []
        },
        "size": 1,
        "nameList": [
            {
                "id": 74997
                "status": "pending"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 45,
        "status": {
            "code": 200,
            "success": true,
            "message": "OK",
            "errors": []
        },
        "size": 5,
        "content": [
            {
                "id": 1260087,
                "pilot": "Jujuki",
                "nameId": 4343,
                "RefId": "3453454"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I split up this object into 2 different object/arrays of data. I want everything with index 0 to go into the first new object, and everything with index 1 to go into the second new object.
What would be best es6 syntax method to use.

Comment: You're looking for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of array content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do Destructuring assignment, like the following:

```js
const data = [{
    timestamp: 345345,
    status: {
      code: 200,
      success: true,
      message: "Success",
      errors: []
    },
    size: 1,
    nameList: [{
      id: 74997,
      status: "pending"
    }]
  },
  {
    timestamp: 45,
    status: {
      code: 200,
      success: true,
      message: "OK",
      errors: []
    },
    size: 5,
    content: [{
      id: 1260087,
      pilot: "Jujuki",
      nameId: 4343,
      RefId: "3453454"
    }]
  }
];


const [firstObj, secondObj] = data;

console.log("the first Object: ", firstObj);
console.log("the second Object: ", secondObj);
```